# Non-breaking spaces break on different font

Tags: html, css, fonts, typekit

I've got a website and I'm looking to change the typekit font from "raleway" to "bpreplay". I've published changes in typekit. However, when I make the changes to CSS, everything is good aside from the way non-breaking spaces are rendered. The only change I'm making is to the font-family. See snippet below. I included a border to help see the issue.

```css
#raleway {
font-family: "raleway";
}

#bpreplay {
font-family: "bpreplay";
}

span {
font-size: 15px;
display: block;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span id="raleway">This is the&nbsp;test with Raleway</span>
<span id="bpreplay">This is the&nbsp;test with BPreplay</span>
</div>
```

Thoughts? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What issue are you talking about ? http://prntscr.com/hmnew9

Comment: In my browser it looks perfectly. What OS and web browser do you use? Submit a screen shot of the issue.

Comment: Well you might have just helped me figure it out to be a local issue. This is how it appears in all major browsers on my Win10 machine: https://imgur.com/a/tnmea